# Invalid attempt to destructure non-interable instance

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

I'm trying to do a simple map in react-native-swiper. So I use this :

```
const onlyOneObservation = [...new Array(pagesCount + 1)].map(([key, idx], i) => this.renderPage(key, idx, i))
```

But with this, I've got this error :

> Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

After research, I don't no where is the problem here.

Comment: Hey, this was the top google result for a similar error I was just having for the last hour with React Native.  I attached the debugger, but couldn't manage to get any actionable info out of it since I'm too much of a JavaScript newbie.  I just wanted to say that the error in my case was that I was setting up a state variable without wrapping it in "React.useState()".  It's a similar problem to what you were facing (we both accidentally created a malformed value that didn't have an array in the correct place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `...` operator destructures an **existing** object / array and makes a new one with the same properties and values. for example:

```
let obj = {
  val1: 'value1',
  val2: 2
}
let obj2 = { ... obj };
console.log(obj2); // will log: { val1: 'value', val2: 2 };
```

But what you do is this: [...new Array(pagesCount+1)]. There are 2 problems here:

1. why even destructure? why not just do (new Array(pagesCount+1)).map( /*code */)?
2. my guess is that it tries to destructure the array before building it, or maybe trying to apply the `...` operator to the `new` keyword, althought im not sure its what actually happens inside. anyway if you really need this destructure (again, can't understand why), im pretty sure `[...(new Array(pagesCount+1))]` should work, or just take the array declaration out.

Comment: @Acam np man. If you wanna read more about spread syntax to use it better, go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
Also, if my answer help you please mark it for the community with the green V near the answer, you will also get reputation for following the community standard way :)